# Problema al acceder a valores en jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jboss

Estoy intentando realizando un desarrollo en java, concretamente en JBOSS, utilzando primefaces. Concretamente, quiero obtener este valor del inputText:

```
<div>                                       
                                            <p:inputText id="matriculaRemolqueTres"  value="#{pc_Detalle.formulario.infraccion.letra1MatriculaRemolque}#{pc_Detalle.formulario.infraccion.letra2y3MatriculaRemolque}" maxlength="3" validatorMessage="#{msg['input.matriculaRemolqueTres.validacion']}" style="text-transform: uppercase" >
                                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$"></f:validateRegex>
                                            <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{pc_Detalle.comprobarMatriculaRemolque}"/>
                                            </p:inputText>
                                        </div>
```

El DTO correspondiente, FormularioDTO, está compuesto de varias clases, una de las cuales es InfraccionDTO. Los getters y setters de esta última son:

```
public String getLetra1MatriculaRemolque() {
        return (letra1MatriculaRemolque == null ? "" : letra1MatriculaRemolque.trim().toUpperCase());
    }

    /**
     * @param letra1MatriculaRemolque ::: El atributo letra1MatriculaRemolque
     */
    public void setLetra1MatriculaRemolque(String letra1MatriculaRemolque) {
        if(null != letra1MatriculaRemolque) {
            this.letra1MatriculaRemolque = letra1MatriculaRemolque.toUpperCase();

        }else {
            this.letra1MatriculaRemolque = "";

        }
    }

    /**
     * @return letra2y3MatriculaRemolque
     */
    public String getLetra2y3MatriculaRemolque() {
        return (letra2y3MatriculaRemolque == null ? "" : letra2y3MatriculaRemolque.trim());
    }

    /**
     * @param letra2y3MatriculaRemolque ::: El atributo  letra2y3MatriculaRemolque
     */
    public void setLetra2y3MatriculaRemolque(String letra2y3MatriculaRemolque) {
        if(null != letra2y3MatriculaRemolque) {
            this.letra2y3MatriculaRemolque = letra2y3MatriculaRemolque.toUpperCase();

        }else {
            this.letra2y3MatriculaRemolque = "";

        }
    }
```

El problema es que siempre me aparece este error:

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException:
> /vistas/registro/detalleRegistro.xhtml @420,397
> value="#{pc_DetalleRegistro.formulario.infraccion.letra1MatriculaRemolque}#{pc_DetalleRegistro.formulario.infraccion.letra2y3MatriculaRemolque}":
> Illegal Syntax for Set Operation 18:55:57,810 INFO  [stdout] (default
> task-1)    at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:99)
> 18:55:57,810 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)   at
> javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:883)

Separo las letras de la matrícula por la estructura de base de datos. ¿Por qué me aparece este error? Si están ambos set y get, y además, según la documentación, se pueden poner varios valores unidos, según he visto en algunos ejemplos. ¿Por qué me pasa ésto? Gracias y saludos

Comment: 18:55:57 es un solo registro?  18:55:57,810 o es un solo registro

Comment: Hola. Se trata de la hora que da JBOSS. Es meramente informativo, sobre la hora en que se produce el fallo. Gracias